# Why with iOS 10.2 UITextFiled Placeholder text default color not gray color?

Tags: ios, colors, uitextfield, placeholder, ios10.2

With iOS 10.2 all the textfields placeholder default color same as the Text color. (means not default gray color),

Answer (score 0):

According to these *latest* docs,description in UIKit:

`open var placeholder: String? // default is nil. string is drawn 70% gray`

the **textfield placeholder text default color** is: **Hex color code : C0C0C0**